# Using two useSwrInfinite hooks in a single infinite scroll not calling second hook - react

Tags: reactjs, vercel, infinite-scroll, swr

I am trying to build a single `InfiniteScroll` that renders cards from two different paginated data sources.  When the user scrolls down to reveal more data, the infinite scroll should request another page of results from the first data source if there are more to render, otherwise it should request another page of results from the second data source.  To do this I'm calling `useSwrInfinite` twice in the same hook, e.g.

```
const useInfiniteFetchAlphasAndBetas = () => {
   const alphaData = useSwrInfinite( ... FETCH_ALPHAS_URL)
   const betaData = useSwrInfinite( ... FETCH_BETAS_URL)

   const hasMoreAlphaResults = alphaData?.length ? alphaData[alphaData.length - 1].pageInfo?.hasNextPage : false
   const hasMoreBetaResults = betaData?.length ? betaData[betaData.length - 1].pageInfo?.hasNextPage : false

   const hasMoreResults = hasMoreAlphaResults || hasMoreBetaResults

   const handleLoadMoreItems = () => {
     if(hasMoreAlphaResults) alphaData.setSize(alphaData.size + 1)
     else if(hasMoreBetaResults) betaData.setSize(betaData.size + 1)
   }

   return { alphaData, betaData, hasMoreResults, handleLoadMoreItems}
}
```

My issue is that while the load-more results logic appears to be working, only the alpha `useSwrInfinite` hook is actually fetching; the beta hook is not fetching at all.  If I switch the order and call the beta `useSwrInfinite` hook first, the alpha hook is never called.

Is it not possible to call more than one `useSwrInfinite` hook at the same time?

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swr-basic-forked-j44frd?file=/src/App.js) that tries to demonstrate the main issue.

Comment: How your fetchers look like?

Comment: linked [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swr-basic-forked-j44frd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You have the same key for both hooks, `abc-${pageIndex}`. So the second hook just returns cached data, it does not know that it needs to fetch other stuff. You need unique keys if you want them to have separates caches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Danila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5650447/danila) answered this.  My issue was that the two `useSwrInfinite` hooks had the same key and were not being stored as separate caches.  Rookie mistake, thank you.